# imap open gives error for custom email laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, imap

I am trying to connect custom email through imap but receiving error `imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {domain.com:993/imap/ssl}. TLS/SSL failure for domain.com:`. Can please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: 143 is never SSL. It is sometimes TLS, which is the /tls parameter.

Comment: sorry It was 993